# MVC Getting number of days between calendar start date and end date

Tags: asp.net-mvc, date, calendar

I have 2 calendars, one for the user to select the start date and the other for the end date. I want to get the value of the difference between the two dates to display the number of days.

```
            decimal period = Convert.ToDecimal((currentApplication.StartDate.Value - currentApplication.EndDate.Value).TotalDays);
            currentApplication.NoOfDays = period;
```

It does work but number of days isn't accurate.

> 22/12 to 22/12 is displayed as 1.00
>
> 22/12 to 23/12 is displayed as -1.00
>
> 22/12 to 24/12 is displayed as -1.00

I thought using `.TotalDays` would be right but the values aren't accurate. Did I use it wrongly or is `.TotalDays` not meant to be used this way?

Comment: What are you expecting ?

Comment: @MairajAhmad I thought it would display the exact number of days. Like 22/12 to 23/12 would be 2 days and 22/12 to 24/12 would be 3 days.

Comment: Just do this `currentApplication.EndDate.Value - currentApplication.StartDate.Value`

Comment: @CucumberNinja How are you setting the values of startDate and endDate fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If number of days isn't accurate when using `.TotalDays` then you can use `Timespan` to get you number of days.

```
TimeSpan tSpan = (currentApplication.EndDate.Value).Subtract(currentApplication.StartDate.Value);
currentApplication.NoOfDays = tSpan.Days;
```

Note: Please make sure `currentApplication.StartDate.Value` and `currentApplication.EndDate.Value` are **DateTime**.

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
decimal period = (currentApplication.startDate.Date - currentApplication.endDate.Date).TotalDays
```

Comment: hello i tried it but i got the following error: Error 1 'System.Nullable<System.DateTime>' does not contain a definition for 'Date' and no extension method 'Date' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable<System.DateTime>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @CucumberNinja Is currentApplication a valid datetime field?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that `startDate` and `endDate` are of type `Nullable<DateTime>`.
You should check `HasValue` for existence of Value first. This code should work for you.

```
if(currentApplication.StartDate.HasValue && currentApplication.EndDate.HasValue)
{
            currentApplication.NoOfDays = (currentApplication.EndDate.Value.Date - currentApplication.StartDate.Value.Date).Days;
}
```